# Dynamically assign value to undefined variable

Tags: javascript

I'm sure there is a simple way to do this, but am stumped for now.

I have many variables defined at the top of my script (here is an example of two):

```
var firstVar,secondVar;
```

Then I have an object which contains those variables:

```
var myObj = { a: {name:firstVar, number:1}, b: {name:secondVar, number:2}
```

I want to assign values to those variables:

```
keys = Object.keys(myObj);

function getAll(e){
   var myArray = [];
   for (var prop in myObj){
      myArray.push(myObj.prop[e]);
   }
return myArray; 
}
```

The behaviour I want is:

```
var nameVars = getAll(name);
// [firstVar,secondVar]
```

But instead it returns:

```
// [undefined,undefined]
```

How else can I get the variables before defining them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then I have an object which contains those variables:

No, it doesn't. It contains a *copy* of the *value* those variables contained as of when you created the object (which is `undefined`, since you've never assigned a value to them). Once created, there is no ongoing link between the object property you've copied the value to and the variable.

Since the object has no enduring link to the variables, there's no way for `getAll` to return the information you've said you want.

---

You've said in a comment that you're building d3 graphs and have the same structure with some variables, and want to avoid repeating yourself. It sounds to me like you want a builder function:

```
function buildObject(firstVar, secondVar) {
    return { a: {name:firstVar, number:1}, b: {name:secondVar, number:2} };
}
```

...which you would then use like this:

```
var obj1 = buildObject("value1", "value2");
// do a graph
var obj2 = buildObject("valueA", "valueB");
// do a graph
```

...or possibly even something that just takes the variables and produces the graph:

```
function makeGraph(firstVar, secondVar) {
    buildTheGraph({ a: {name:firstVar, number:1}, b: {name:secondVar, number:2} });
}
```

---

I don't think it is, but if it's the *names* you want, just put them in quotes (and also `myArray.push(myObj.prop[e]);` should be `myArray.push(myObj[prop][e]);` and `getAll(name)` should be `getAll("name")`), but again there's no link to the variables at all:

```js
// Since they're not used, we don't even need these: var firstVar, secondVar;

var myObj = { a: { name: "firstVar", number: 1 }, b: { name: "secondVar", number: 2 } };

function getAll(e) {
  var myArray = [];
  for (var prop in myObj) {
    myArray.push(myObj[prop][e]);
  }
  return myArray;
}

var nameVars = getAll("name");
console.log(nameVars);
```

...but note that having the names doesn't help you get the variable values later (unless you use `eval`, which you should seek to avoid).

Comment: So does this mean that if I want this behaviour, I should define all the variables with some dummy value up front?

Comment: @Jonathan_W: The value of the variables is irrelevant. The key thing here is that there's no link between the object property and the variable.

Comment: @Jonathan_W: I think this is an X/Y problem. What is it you expect to do with the value of `myObj.a.name`?

Comment: @Jonathan_W try using prop[e] only instead of myObj.prop[e] in your getAll function and your e should be a string i.e "name"

Comment: I would like to assign it a value to the variable. The reason is because I have many variables like firstvar, secondVar that I am populating for a D3 graph, and would like wrap it in a function so as not to have to repeat myself.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the question says he wants to assign value to the variables firstVar and secondVar and get those values.. not get the values as a string "firstVar", "secondVar".. so -1 for this

Comment: @Jonathan_W: I suggest posting a new question asking how to do that, with an [mcve] showing where you're repeating yourself. Then we can help you solve the real problem (and possibly demonstrate a technique you can reuse for similar problems in the future).

Comment: @Sohlowmawn: As I said above prior to that bit: *"**I don't think it is, but** if it's the* names *you want..."* The answer is primarily: There is no link.

Comment: Thank you @T.J.Crowder. Just to check - according to SO protocol, should I mark this as a correct answer?

Comment: @Jonathan_W: It's up to you. :-) I think the thing you asked to do, you can't do, which is what this answer says, so in that sense yes. But... (BTW, from that d3 comment, I've added a couple of concepts above which *may* be relevant, but if not that separate question with details is the way to go.)