# Dynamically accessing global undefined variables (example in D3), DRY

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dry

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812891/dynamically-assign-value-to-undefined-variable/38812919?noredirect=1#comment64993521_38812919), I would like to create a DRY way of creating Js variables for a D3 graph which represents daily sentiment analysis of UK newspapers.

Here is some example code from my script:

```
var guardian,independent; // many more here
var gLine,gChart; // many more here
var iLine,iChart; // many more here
```

I am storing the newspaper-specific variables in an object:

```
var allObjects = {  guardian : {line : gLine,chart : gChart},
independent : {line : iLine,chart : iChart}}// and so on for each newspaper
```

I assign the variables using functions as follows:

```
 function makeLine(name){return d3.svg.line().y(function(d) { return y(d[name]); }); }
// and so on for each newspaper attribute in AllObjects
```

Rather than repeating myself all the time, making each object individually:

```
makeLine('guardian'); makeLine('independent'); // etc
```

...which works fine, I would like to be able to iterate over all the newspapers, and assign the objects with a single function for all newspapers, something like:

```
var allFunctions = {line:  makeLine(),chart:  makeChart()};

  function make(type){ 
    var myFunc = allFunctions.type;
    for(var prop in allObjects){prop.type = myFunc(type);}
}
```

So that `make(line)` would assign `gLine`, `iLine`, etc

The problem is that as the variables in `allObjects.guardian` are undefined, this method isn't working.

Any suggestions as how to refactor in this way?

Comment: :-) Really not trying to be a pain here, but "complete" means something one can take and run and see the problem, etc. In particular, it's hard to see what `makeLine` is supposed to do given the indirection through the `d` object that d3 calls your callback with. Sorry to be frustrating, not least because it was I who suggested posting a question with *more* details originally. :-) But if I could make out what you needed to do, I could help you do it, and I just can't quite get it from the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Rather than repeating myself all the time, making each object individually:
>
> ```
>  makeLine('guardian'); makeLine('independent'); // etc
> ```
>
> ...which works fine, I would like to be able to iterate over all the newspapers, and assign the objects with a single function for all newspapers

If I'm reading that right, your "something like" is *really* close, see comments:

```
var allFunctions = {line:  makeLine, chart: makeChart};
// Note no () here ----------------^ or here --------^
// We want the reference to the function, we don't want to call it (yet)

// Assuming `type` is "line", "chart", etc.
function make(type){ 
    // Note brackets: We want the property whose name is in the type
    // variable, not a property actually called "type"
    var myFunc = allFunctions[type];
    //                       ^----^------ We want the property whose name is in
    //                                    the `type` variable, not a property
    //                                    actually *called* "type"
    for (var prop in allObjects) {
        allObjects[prop][type] = myFunc(prop);
        //        ^----^-----^----------- Brackets again as above
    }
}
```

Comment: Blast, I had `type` and `prop` confused. That line near the end should read `allObjects[prop][type] = myFunc(prop);`; hit refresh if that's not what you see.

Comment: Basically I hadn't realised that variables in JS were references, not objects in themselves as in OOP programming. Works now, thank you.

Comment: @Jonathan_W: I'm afraid I'm not quite following "...references, not objects in themselves..." Variables in JavaScript are essentially identical to variables in other OOP languages like Java or C#. In all of those languages, a variable contains a **value**, and the value might be a number or boolean, etc., or might be an object reference; and in all of those languages, when a variable contains an object reference, the object itself exists separately from the variable (the variable contains a reference, not an object). There's no significant difference in JS in this regard.